# Build issue with code using boost::interprocess on VS 2010

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I am trying to build a piece of code in VS 2010 that is commonly found online as an example of having a map in shared memory.

```
#include <boost\interprocess\managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost\interprocess\containers\map.hpp>

typedef boost::interprocess::map<long,long,
            std::less<long>,
            boost::interprocess::allocator<std::pair<long,long>,
                boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> >
        shmap;

boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory segment1(
    boost::interprocess::create_only, 
    "MySharedMemory", 655360); //segment name and size in bytes

shmap *rp = segment1.construct<shmap>("SharedMap")(
    std::less<long>(), segment1.get_segment_manager());
```

I get this error which boggles my mind. Any ideas?

```
error C2338: (container_detail::is_same<std::pair<const Key, T>, typename A::value_type>::value)
```

Comment: That can't be the complete error message?

Comment: it's sufficient: is_same+'const Key'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be

```
typedef boost::interprocess::map
<long,long,std::less<long>,
boost::interprocess::allocator<std::pair<const long,long>, 
boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> > shmap;
```

Since internal check is `is_same<std::pair<const Key, T>, Allocator::value_type>`